# Close active editortab when in normal VimMode when using VsCode/Vim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I am trying to close the active editor tab when pressing a key like "c" to close the active tab.

Tried the following element in my keybindings.json

```
    {
        "key": "c",
        "command": "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor",
        "when" : "normalVimMode"
    }
```

But this also closes the tab when i am in edit mode. Any clue how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following snippet to `settings.json` solves my problem:

```
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["c"],
            "commands": [
                "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor"
            ]
        }
    ]
```